# strotime return false when i try to convert a string with US\Eastern timezone, which timezone should i use instead of that?

Tags: php, timezone

If i do

```
$time = strtotime( '2013-3-16 11:40:00 US/Eastern' );
echo $time;
```

$time is false. The string is generated programmatically so i could alter the timezone to a supported one, what should i use?

Answer (score 4):

I think this should work:

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-j H:i:s', 
          '2013-3-16 11:40:00', new DateTimeZone('US/Eastern'));

print $time->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Well, `strtotime('2013-3-16 11:40:00 EDT');` should do the same thing (maybe [this page](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/definition/index.htm) will help)

Answer (score 2):

```
date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern'); 
$time = strtotime( '2013-3-16 11:40:00' );
echo $time;
```

Comparing with @One Trick Pony it produces same result.
[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fd0-eha)

Answer (score 1):

see this page

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

help you for set timezone